# How to import npm module from a file inside a subfolder?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, fs

I have a project directory with name **kickstart**. Inside it there is a file **new.js** in the location 'kickstart/pages/campaigns'. I wanted to use `npm` package `fs` in this file. So I typed `npm install --save fs` with kickstart as current working directory in cmd. This installed `fs` in folder `node_modules` inside 'kickstart'. But when I try to import fs from new.js by writing:

```
import fs from 'fs';
```

After that when I run the kickstart project, it says fs not found? What is the problem?
I have also tried installing fs with 'campaigns' as current directory but still nothing changes. Why?

```
Error Log: This dependency was not found:

* fs in ./pages/campaigns/new.js?entry
```

To install it, you can run: `npm install --save fs`

Comment: Could you also show us your package.json file?

Comment: please show us error log.

Comment: package.json contains the entry "fs" in dependencies. for error log check edit in question.

Comment: Are you using webpack ? if yes, can you paste your config ?

Comment: `fs` is part of Node.js, you should not install it with npm or add it to your package.json file. What version of Node.js are you running? Do you run it with the `--experimental-modules` flag? [You cannot use ESM in *js files but only in *.mjs files](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Comment: I installed latest nodejs a few days ago only. I don't run it with --experimental-modules flag. And also I don't use webpack. Now how to solve the issue?

Comment: Read the link I posted.

Comment: @dreadedHarvester you will need to give more information unfortunately. When you say 'when i run the project' what does this mean? are you building with node? ie. node yourentryscript.js

Comment: actually I use command "npm run dev" and I am using nextjs in my app.